# Node JS Error: EEXIST: file already exists, uv_pipe_open while trying to export a sequelize model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am getting an error while using sequelize model from one file in Node JS and trying to export it.

```
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, uv_pipe_open
    at new Socket (node:net:361:24)
    at process.getStdin [as stdin] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:226:17)
    at get (<anonymous>)
    at getOwn (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:189:5)
    at NativeModule.syncExports (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:311:31)
    at NativeModule.compileForPublicLoader (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:277:10)
    at loadNativeModule (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:49:9)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:818:15)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

The code I used for initializing squalize connection in below /config/common.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

function Common(){};

Common.prototype.AdminDBName = "ldgybxav_anocracy";
Common.prototype.AdminDBUID = "ldgybxav_allyadminmedi2021";
Common.prototype.AdminDBPWD = "MediAlly202!";

Common.prototype.setSequelize =  function(db_name, db_user, db_password) {
    var sequelize = new Sequelize(db_name, db_user, db_password, {
      timezone: '+05:30',
      host:'103.108.220.123',
      
      dialect:'mysql',
      pool: {
          max: 5,
          min: 0,
          acquire: 30000,
          idle: 10000
        }
    });
  
    return sequelize;
  }



  Common.prototype.setPharmaDBConn =  function(model) {
    
  
    var sequelize = this.setSequelize('ldgybxav_' + 'anocracy' , 'ldgybxav_allyadminmedi2021', 'MediAlly202!');
  
    var entityObject = model(sequelize,Sequelize);
    
    return entityObject;
  }



  module.exports = new Common()
```

I tried to call this from the file /routes/users/usermaster.js from where I am getting this error which now I tried to catch inside the code itself and run fine. But I need resolution for this as not able to access my db operations due to this problem.

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var common = require('../../config/common');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var UserMasterModel1 = require('../../models/UserMaster1');
var UserMaster1 = null;

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    UserMaster1 = common.setPharmaDBConn(UserMasterModel1);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    if (error.code === 'EEXIST') {
      res.status(201).send({'message' : 'UserMasterModel file already opend'});
      return;
    }
  }
    if(UserMaster1 == null || UserMaster1 == undefined) 
    { res.status(201).send({'message': 'No UserMaster Record Found, Please Try Again!'}); return;}
    next();
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Welcome To Annocracy User Master');
});

router.get('/user_name/:user_name/user_psw/:user_psw/role_level/:role_level', (req,res) => {
  
   const { Op } = require("sequelize");

   UserMaster1.findAll({
    where : {
             [Op.and] : [{user_name : req.params.user_name}, 
              {user_psw : req.params.user_psw}, 
              {role_level: req.params.role_level}]
            }
    })
    
     .then( (resultSet)=> res.status(200).send(resultSet) )
     .catch(error => { console.log(error); res.status(500).send('Exception : Something Wrong is given as input! Please Try again' + error)})
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am also attaching the model used for this /models/UserMaster1.js

```
module.exports =(sequelize, Sequelize )=>{
    const UserMaster = sequelize.define("UserMaster", {
        user_id:{
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT(11),
            primaryKey:  true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        user_name: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
        user_psw: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
        user_ph: {type: Sequelize.BIGINT(10), allowNull: false},
        role_level: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
        supervisor_id: {type: Sequelize.BIGINT(10), allowNull: false},
        role_id: {type: Sequelize.BIGINT(10), allowNull: true},
        role_id_name: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
        record_created_by: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true},
        record_created_date: {type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: true},
        record_modified_by: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true},
        record_modified_date: {type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: true},
    },{
        timestamps:false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'UserMaster'
    });
    return UserMaster;
}
```